# Check if a method exists in an extended class but not parent class

Tags: php

With `method_exists`, it checks all methods, including the parent class.

Example:

```
class Toot {
    function Good() {}
}

class Tootsie extends Toot {
    function Bad() {}
}

function testMethodExists() {
    // true
    var_dump(method_exists('Toot', 'Good'));

    // false
    var_dump(method_exists('Toot', 'Bad'));

    // true
    var_dump(method_exists('Tootsie', 'Good'));

    // true
    var_dump(method_exists('Tootsie', 'Bad'));
}
```

How can I check that the method only exists on the current class and not parent class (ie. `Tootsie`)?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to know if the method exists in a given child regardless the existence in a parent class you can do it like this:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
if ($reflectionClass->getMethod($method_name)->class == $class_name) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since v. 4.0.5 php has [get_parent_class()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) method, that returns parent class. So you can handle it without relflection:

```
class A
{
    function a() { /* ... */}    
    function b() { /* ... */}    
}
class B extends A
{
    function b() { /* ... */}    
    function c() { /* ... */}    
}

function own_method($class_name, $method_name)
{    
    if (method_exists($class_name, $method_name))
    {
        $parent_class = get_parent_class($class_name);
        if ($parent_class !== false) return !method_exists($parent_class, $method_name);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

var_dump(own_method('B', 'a')); // false
var_dump(own_method('B', 'b')); // false 
var_dump(own_method('B', 'c')); // true
```

Comment: notice: This function returns false when the extending class overwrites a parent method. I'm looking for a method that returns true if a method exists in the extending class even if that method overwrites an parent method.

Answer (score 2):

you can use reflection

```
$refl = new ReflectionClass($class_name); 
   
if($refl->hasMethod($method_name)){
       //do your stuff here 
}
```

for more information [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems like it suffers from the same problem as `method_exists` as well - "Parent methods (regardless of visibility) are also available to a ReflectionObject." from http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php#100660

Answer (score 2):

Based on the @sleepless answer above, but working in case the method doesn't exist at all:

```
function methodImplementedInClass($className, $methodName) {
    // If this class doesn't have the method at all, return false
    if (!method_exists($className, $methodName)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Now check if the method was implemented in this class or in some parent
    return (new ReflectionClass($className))->getMethod($methodName)->class == $className;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the question was *Check if a method exists in an extended class but not parent class* **from the parent class**

Taking the above example from Elantcev Mikhail, it would look more like this:-

```
class A
{
        function a() { /* ... */}    
        function b() { /* ... */}    
        public function own_method( $method_name )
        {    
            if (method_exists($this, $method_name))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
}
class B extends A
{
    function b() { /* ... */}    
    function c() { /* ... */}    
}

$b = new B;

var_dump($b->own_method('c')); // true
```

Why would you want to do this?

I have a class BaseModel in which I format hints for attributes in the extended model:

```
class BaseModel
{
    public function attributeHelp($attributeName)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'hints') && array_key_exists($attributeName, $this->hints()))
        {
            return '<i html for nicely formatted hint'
                . $this->hints()[$attributeName]
                . '"></i>';
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then in my data model

```
class Customer extends BaseModel
{
    public function hints()
    {
        return [
           'customer_name' => 'please use your fullname ...',
           'some other attribute' => 'some other description'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using reflection and checking the actual class involved in the Reflection Method.

```
<?php

class Base {
    public function BaseOnly() {
    }

    public function Extended() {
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public function ChildOnly() {
    }

    public function Extended() {
    }
}

function childMethodExists($baseClass, $childClass, $methodName) {
    if (!method_exists($childClass, $methodName)) {
        return false; // doesn't exist in the child class or base class
    }
    if (!method_exists($baseClass, $methodName)) {
        return true; // only exists on child class, as otherwise it would have returned above
    }
    // now to check if it is overloaded
    $baseMethod = new ReflectionMethod($baseClass, $methodName);
    $childMethod = new ReflectionMethod($childClass, $methodName);
    return $childMethod->class !== $baseMethod->class;
}

var_dump(childMethodExists(Base::class, Child::class, 'BaseOnly')); // false
var_dump(childMethodExists(Base::class, Child::class, 'ChildOnly')); // true
var_dump(childMethodExists(Base::class, Child::class, 'Neither')); // false
var_dump(childMethodExists(Base::class, Child::class, 'Extended')); // true
```