# PHP Check if parent exists if inherited (current scope instead of $this)

Tags: php, inheritance, parent

*I hope i can write this down clearly*

Case:

I have a *base* class `Foo`.

Foo **can** have a method *(in example)* `::run`.

Another class `Bar` extends `Foo` and has its own method `::run`. `Bar` *(and the dev writing `Bar`)* does not know if the parent `Foo` **has** or **will have** the method `::run`.

This is why `Bar` wants to call the current method on `parent` anyway.

The helper method `::callParentMethodIfExists`should do its job and check if `$method` exists on `parent`.

**So far so good:**

- calling `Bar::run`
- `Bar::run` calls `::callParentMethodIfExists`
- `::callParentMethodIfExists` calls `parent::run` if exists.

**Problem:**

If now a class `Baz` extends `Bar` and `Baz` does **not** have the `::run` method then:

- calling `Baz::run` which is inherited from `Bar`
- executing `Bar::run`
- `Bar::run` calls `::callParentMethodIfExists`
- `::callParentMethodIfExists` calls `::parentMethodExists` and checks if *(and thats the problem)* `$this` (`Baz`) has a parent method `::run`

So this turns out true, since `Baz` has a `parent::run` (i.e. `Bar::run` ofc) **but** this is not the scope that i should check it from.

**In Short**

Helper methods `::callParentMethodIfExists` and `::parentMethodExists` should **not** check on `$this`. They should check on scope *first occurrence of method in question*.

---

**Code**

**Working case**

```
class Foo
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Bar extends \Foo
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->callParentMethodIfExists(__FUNCTION__);

        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * Calls the given parent method if exists.
     *
     * @param string $method
     *
     * @return null|mixed
     */
    protected function callParentMethodIfExists($method)
    {
        if ($this->parentMethodExists($this, $method)) {
            return parent::$method();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed  $class  An object (class instance) or a string (class name).
     * @param string $method The method name.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function parentMethodExists($class, $method)
    {
        foreach (class_parents($class) as $parent) {
            if (method_exists($parent, $method)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Baz extends \Bar{}

(new \Baz())->run();
// out:
// Foo::run
// Bar::run
```

**Not working case**

```
class Foo{}

class Bar extends \Foo
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->callParentMethodIfExists(__FUNCTION__);

        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * Calls the given parent method if exists.
     *
     * @param string $method
     *
     * @return null|mixed
     */
    protected function callParentMethodIfExists($method)
    {
        if ($this->parentMethodExists($this, $method)) {
            return parent::$method();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed  $class  An object (class instance) or a string (class name).
     * @param string $method The method name.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function parentMethodExists($class, $method)
    {
        foreach (class_parents($class) as $parent) {
            if (method_exists($parent, $method)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Baz extends \Bar{}

(new \Baz())->run();
// out:
// Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Foo::run() in
```

As you can see on *not working case* the `Foo` class does not have the `::run` method.

Called class (`$this`) is `Baz`.

`Baz` inherited method `::run` from `Bar`.

`Bar::run` calls `::callParentMethodIfExists`.

Falsely the both helper methods check on `$this` (`Baz`) and *find out* that `Baz` has a `parent::run`.

Actually the both helper methods **should** check on **current scope** (`Bar`) and *find out* that `Bar` does **not** have a `parent::run`.

---

I hope this is understandable and somebody knows a solution.

Thanks in advance!

/cottton

**EDIT** `::callParentMethodIfExists` and `::parentMethodExists` also could be defined on `Foo` or included as `trait`.

Comment: Ouch, I have a cramp in my scrolling finger :-(

Comment: This seems rather roundabout. Why not just declare `Foo::run` final?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I cant. In actual code the "Host" class calls "callbacks"(?). Its Phalcon\Mvc\Model which can have `::beforeSave` ect.

Comment: This solution will likely work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66572063/68567

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the situation but I would write `Bar::run()` as simple as that:

```
public function run()
{
    if (method_exists('Foo', 'run')) {
        Foo::run();
    }

    echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You know that `Bar extends Foo`, there is no need for so much investigation about parent classes and all the stuff.

The children of `Bar` may redefine method `run()` or they may not. As long as they call `parent::run();` in their new definition, the call chain will eventually reach `Bar::run()` that calls `Foo::run()` if it exists.

Comment: I need that dynamically. In actual code the two methods are traits. So its not fix where the cal comes from ect.